# Django; adapt same validator with multiple fileds

Tags: python, django, django-models

***Objective :***

I want to override `first_name` and `last_name` from `AbstractUser model`.

***What I want exactly :***

I want to create `validator` that tells if either `first_name` or `last_name` is filled. So I want to adapt the same validator with the two parameters. How can I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the model's `clean()` method. For reference, saving a model instance through the `ORM` does not call the model's `clean()` method.

So when you subclass `AbstractUser`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class User(AbstractUser):

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

        if not self.first_name and not self.last_name:
            raise ValidationError({
                'first_name': ValidationError('Please set this', code='error1'),
                'last_name': ValidationError('... or this', code='error2')
            })
```

Don't forget to configure your `Django` project as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).
You also need to make sure that your forms using this model always implement the fields `first_name` and `last_name`, otherwise you get an `ValueError`.

So every time you use a `ModelForm` in conjunction with your `User` model `clean()` gets called. E.g. in `Django`'s [`UserChangeForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L124), `UserCreationForm`, etc.